# Distribution of sample standard deviation extracted from a normally distributed population

Tags: variance, sample-size, sample

I was playing around with the sample standard deviation extracted by the following code

```
vari = numeric()
for (i in 1:1000){
  test = rnorm(n,6,3)
  vari = c(vari,sd(test))
}
hist(vari)
qqnorm(vari)
```

I tried n=10,100 and 100, and got the following histogram and qqplot:
[image]

[image]

It actually indicates that the sample standard deviation is normally distributed. 
Can anyone explain why exactly this happens?

Comment: You have 'played around' with the standard deviation, not with the variance ?

Comment: Just edited it. I don't know what I was thinking..

Comment: The chi distribution (square root of a chi-square) is right skewed, but as the df increase it rapidly approaches symmetry (a fair bit more rapidly than the corresponding chi-square; its skewness coefficient is about 1/4 of that of a chi-square if $n$ is not very small; equivalently, a chi distribution at some given d.f. is about as skewed as a chi-square with 16 times the d.f.; i.e. a chi(15) is roughly about as skew as a chi-square(240)). Consequently sample sd's from a normal distrbution (which will be scaled chi) will generally look nearly symmetric and are typically quite close to normal.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. Somehow I was confused about the difference between chi and chi square distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution looks normal but it is not; it is a little skewed if you look carefully. The actual distribution of the standard deviation can be derived analytically starting from the fact that for a normal population

$$Y = \frac{\left(n-1\right)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2 \left(n-1 \right)$$

and using the transformation rule afterwards. If you carry out these steps you will see that the resulting distribution has a quadratic exponent much like the normal distribution and this largely determines the shape. **Hint:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution.